# Laravel 4.2 mail suddenly stop working in Amazon ec2 linux

Tags: linux, email, laravel-4, amazon-ec2, swiftmailer

> Framework: Laravel 4.2
>
> Server: Amazon ec2 Linux

Yesterday `\Mailing::send`  was still working and then suddenly today it stop sending emails. I don't know what has happened.

here is my `mail.php` config:

```
<?php

return array(

    /* x
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "log"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'mail',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => 'mail.1fx.cash',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */
    'port' => 587,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => array('address' => 'info@philwebservicescloud.net', 'name' => '1Fx Cash'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => 'tls',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => 'info@philwebservicescloud.net',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Password
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may set the password required by your SMTP server to send out
    | messages from your application. This will be given to the server on
    | connection so that the application will be able to send messages.
    |
    */

    'password' => '******',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail "Pretend"
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When this option is enabled, e-mail will not actually be sent over the
    | web and will instead be written to your application's logs files so
    | you may inspect the message. This is great for local development.
    |
    */

    'pretend' => false,

);
```

I have tried restarting the instance. Its still not sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find out if there is any mails stuck in email spool. If it is empty then it is lavarels problem. Otherwise mail is stuck and could be affected by antispam filter. To resolve it fill this [form](https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request)

Comment: Yes mike I think you almost got it. I did a `cron job` that sends to email in `every minute`. I went to sleep and next thing in the morning i received 1000 emails in the inbox and 1000 emails in the spam. what will i do? time will fix it?

Comment: Should I just wait for the mails to process and gmail will remove it as spam?

Comment: Amazon is limiting email amount you can send. They could be stuck in spool then sent as whole pack. I recommend to fill out form and remove emails from spam. Should help in time.

Comment: Yes, im now waiting for response, please up vote my question :)